# C# add infinite number of options to a Menu Item

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

So I have a menu app where a dish might have one or more options and a price addition for each. Like a Hamburger item, then add bacon for 1$, Mushrooms add 50c, etc.

This is kind of what I'm thinking. Do I need to predefine 7 or 8 menu options that each menu item can take in? Or can I have 1 Option/Price and each gets added as more options are needed?

UI wise I'd like to have a Menu Item in a Card layout. MenuItemName, MenuItemPrice, then below Options, if another option is needed an (Add) button would be there so a new option line could be added.

```
using System;

namespace MenuConsole
{
public interface IMenuOption
{
    void OptionName();
    void OptionPrice();
}

public class MenuItem : IMenuOption
{
    public string MenuItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal MenuItemPrice { get; set; }

    public void OptionName()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OptionPrice()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}



public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing? The code you shared is of Console Application.... What type of application you are building?

Comment: Do you want to build a wpf application? Maybe try to get started with something simple like a few buttons and a dropdown list to understand the basics, the move on with your project

Comment: Most likely a MVC or Blazor App... Just did a bit in console trying to think things out a little.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define list of menu options in menu item:

```
public interface IMenuOption
{
    void OptionName();
    void OptionPrice();
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public string MenuItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal MenuItemPrice { get; set; }
    public List<IMenuOption> Options { get; set; }
}
```